# Unable to download. The application request limit has been reached

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using `BackgroundTransferRequest` to download files, I have more than 6,500 mp3 that user can download them at once clicking on download all button Or user can download individual file.

I cannot add more than 25 files in download `BackgroundTransferRequest`. What is the workaround with it to add more than 25 files in download queue.

When it reaches the level, the exception is

```
Unable to download. The application request limit has been reached
```

Code for adding in Queue, After all files are added. I am processing download.

```
transferFileName = aya.DownloadUri;
Uri transferUri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString(aya.DownloadUri), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

BackgroundTransferRequest transferRequest = new BackgroundTransferRequest(transferUri);
transferRequest.Method = "GET";

string downloadFile = transferFileName.Substring(transferFileName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
Uri downloadUri = new Uri(downloadLocation + aya.ChapterID + "/" + downloadFile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
transferRequest.DownloadLocation = downloadUri;

transferRequest.Tag = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", downloadFile, aya.ID, aya.ChapterID);
transferRequest.TransferPreferences = TransferPreferences.AllowBattery;

BackgroundTransferService.Add(transferRequest);
```

Comment: could you put some code so we can see how you do the request processing ?

Answer (score 2):

You *must* attach an event handler to `BackgroundTransferRequest.StatusChanged`. On appropriate state you *must* explicitly remove transfer from `BackgroundTransferService`. As you may now, the requests have to be removed from `BackgroundTransferService` manually. All that is explained in detail in [introduction to background transfers on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202959%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

You should create a queue of files to download, start with placing first 25 transfers in `BackgroundTransferService` and after the `BackgroudTransferService.Remove(..)`, you can start next transfer from your queue.